# My modal service doesn't open when i declare another service in the constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

So i got this method for login in angular

```
email: string = "";
  password: string = "";
  login() {
    const credentials = {
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password
    };
    this.userService.login(credentials).subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
        sessionStorage.setItem('email', response.email)
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Login failed:', error);
      }
    );
    this.modalService.dismissAll();
  }
```

which i use from my own userService method

```
login(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.url + "/login", data, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    });
  }
```

but everytime i declare the userService in the main page constructor and implement the logic my modal doesn't work

```
constructor(private userService:UserService,private modalService:NgbModal,
              private router:Router) {
  }
```

I tried migrating the methods to one files to see if that was the problem it still didn't work.I expect for the modal to work but it doesn't open

Comment: please share more code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Comment: Many details missing, where do you open the modal? Do you see error messages in the console?

Comment: I found the problem it was that i had forgotten to add HttpClientModule in app.module

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it was that i had forgotten to add HttpClientModule in app.module.ts  because i was getting an error in console which was:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[_UserService -> _UserService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
```